# How to access datasource fields in an ASP.NET Repeaters ItemDataBound event?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, itemdatabound

I have a Repeater control that is being bound to the result of a Linq query.

I want to get the value of one of the datasource's fields in the ItemDataBound event, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use: `e.Item.DataItem`.

Example: [Repeater.ItemDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx)

```
// This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.
void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
      e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
  {
    if (((Evaluation)e.Item.DataItem).Rating == "Good")
    {
      ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("RatingLabel")).Text= "<b>***Good***</b>";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 46):

Depending on the DataSource...
If your DataSource is a DataTable, then your DataItem contains a DataRowView:

```
protected void rptMyReteater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Button b = e.Item.FindControl("myButton") as Button; 
        DataRowView drv = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        b.CommandArgument = drv.Row["ID_COLUMN_NAME"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The data that is used for the current item can be found from the EventArgs.

```
RepeaterItemEventArgs e

e.Item.DataItem
```