# Conditional loading in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, asprepeater

in my repeater i have to load 2 out of 4 different images depends on some conditions.

here is 4 images

```
if (<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Voted") %> == "true") 'load these 2 images
    <img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Dostuff"
         id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uid") %>'
         src="../../Images/badge-circle-plus-24-ns.png" />
    <img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Dostuff"
         id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uid") %>'
         src="../../Images/arrow-down-24-ns.png" />
else 'load these 2 
    <img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Dostuff" 
         id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uid") %>'
         src="../../Images/arrow-up-24-ns.png"  />
    <img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Dostuff"
         id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uid") %>'
         src="../../Images/arrow-down-24-ns.png"  />
```

How do i get around this problem?

Comment: and what exactly *is* the problem?

Comment: When i use such if expression i am endning up with : Container does not exsists in the current context

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289917/eval-if-statement-in-repeater

Comment: @Timsen: You can format text as code in your post by indenting it by at least four spaces.

Comment: you would be better using the `ItemDataBound` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) - all your code will be in the code-behind and their should be no issues with container not existing.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/829015/880990, [INFO: ASP.NET Code-Behind Model Overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303247)

Comment: Found my answer here after quite a lot of searching : http://forums.asp.net/t/1766065.aspx/1    the last answer

Comment: You could probably answer your question with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can; see this for [more information](http://forums.asp.net/t/1509415.aspx/1).  Essentially, you should format it as:

```
<% if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Voted")  == "true") {  %>
    <img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Dostuff"
         id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uid") %>'
         src="../../Images/badge-circle-plus-24-ns.png" />
    <img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Dostuff"
         id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uid") %>'
         src="../../Images/arrow-down-24-ns.png" />
<% } else { %>
    <img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Dostuff" 
         id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uid") %>'
         src="../../Images/arrow-up-24-ns.png"  />
    <img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Dostuff"
         id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uid") %>'
         src="../../Images/arrow-down-24-ns.png"  />
<% } %>
```

I'm not sure if that's completely supported, so you could also consider trying:

```
<img style="cursor: pointer" onclick="Dostuff"
         id='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Uid") %>'
         src='../../Images/<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Voted")  == "true" ? "badge-circle-plus-24-ns.png" : "arrow-up-24-ns.png" %>' />
  .
  .
```

The latter uses a conditional and renders the appropriate image depending on the condition.